# Import users to groups using CSV

Tags: powershell

Hi im fairly new at the whole scripting scene, and im trying to make a script that will import users, i have listet in a csv file into a AD group.
What i would like to know is, how the format should go.
My csv file contrains " Group|Name|SamAccountName|Path|Enabled|Password"
I would like to know how this line is configured

```
"add-adgroupmember -identity $user.Group -member"
```

Comment: Do you want to put the user into the group? Or do you want to add the AD-PrincipalGroupMmbership - make the user as member of a group?

Comment: member of a group

Comment: ok - so which delimiter is used in your csv?

Comment: "Group|Name|SamAccountName|Path|Enabled|Password" this ?

Comment: is '|' the [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)? - or is it ',' - or is it ';' or is it '\t'...

Comment: its written in excel so i guess the Boxes ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, that should work

but before using the script you definetly should get to know  something about:

[Add-ADGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx)

[Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617203.aspx)

And you should be shure about your CSV and the delimiters.
With the wrong cmdlet or using of a cmdlet you can produce a lot of troubles in an ActiveDirectory :)

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "P:\\ath\to\your\file.csv" | % {

  $group = get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $_.Group } -Server dom-company.com
  $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $_.SamAccountName } -Server dom-company.com
  if($group.Name -eq $_.Group -and $user.SamAccountName -eq $_.SamAccountName){
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $group
  }

}
```

Comment: with this code it will still take the "DC=server,DC=com" path from the CSV file ?

Comment: Ehm nope - but if you try to understand the code you'll know how to fix it. Otherwise - and that's what I think you should start something easier in powershell and learn some basics before administrating the AD - sorry but I won't do your work and let you run scripts you dont understand in an active directory

Comment: Hint: | % means foreach